# Unexpected behavior when using a custom action filter attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to reproduce the same functionality that the boiler plate account action filter does but with a different value that is needed to perform an action. I've come across a weird state of events. Here is my `ActionFilterAttribute` definition:

```
public class RequireMemberSelectionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// When the decorated action is executing, redirect to the member selection view if a member is not selected.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a_filterContext">Filter context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext a_filterContext)
    {
        if ((Session.Current.Preferences.MemberID ?? 0) > 0)
            return;

        String returnUrl = null;
        if (a_filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
            returnUrl = a_filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

        a_filterContext.Redirect("Builder", "ListMembers", new { ReturnUrl=returnUrl });
    }
}
```

This is how I am using it within my code. I want to make sure that the session has a member ID before going to the `SelectArea` action:

```
    // GET: Builder/SelectArea
    [RequireMemberSelection]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SelectArea()
    {
        var memberId = _session.Preferences.MemberID ?? 0;

        return View();
    }

    // GET: Builder/ListMembers/{returnUrl}
    [Route("Builder/ListMembers")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ListMembers(String returnUrl = "")
    {
        var members = await _repository.GetMembers();

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View(members);
    }

    // GET: Builder/SelectMember/{id}
    [Route("Builder/SelectMember/{id}")]
    public ActionResult SelectMember(int id, String returnUrl = "")
    {
        _session.Preferences.MemberID = id;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            return RedirectPermanent(returnUrl);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The unexpected behavior is that when a link is clicked on the `ListMembers.cshtml` view, instead of going to the `SelectMember` action it tries to go to `SelectArea` and so starts all over again.

Here is the exact link from `ListMembers.cshtml`. I copied it right from the rendered page in the browser:

> http://localhost:61286/Builder/SelectMember/1?returnUrl=%2FBuilder%2FSelectArea

I feel like there is something about the action filter that I do not understand.

Following is how I generate the link in my razor view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "SelectMember", new { id = 1, returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
```

Comment: How do you generate the link in `ListMembers.cshtml`?

Comment: Fair question. I use `Html.ActionLink`. I added the line to the end of my post above.

Comment: I would double check if when you do `_session.Preferences.MemberID = id;` that is reflected in your filter `Session.Current.Preferences.MemberID`

Comment: What's with the RedirectPermanent in the SelectMember action? Is that instructing the browser to always go to Builder/SelectArea whenever Builder/SelectMember/1 is requested?

Comment: See, I thought that `RedirectPermanent ` meant that the current page would be overwritten in the history journal. It is something completely different. Like usual, the MSDN documentation tells me nothing. I should have looked it up on google. How do I do what I was wanting to do?